# Consume SOAP WebService on Sencha?

Tags: web-services, extjs, soap, sencha-touch

I have been doing some test about a HelloWorld on sencha, but anyway I can't get it to work con a responseXML. My code is something like this...

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
       url: 'http://url/MobileService/MobileWS.asmx',
       callbackKey: 'callback',
       scope: 'this',
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld"'},
       success: function(response) {
          // OK
           alert("ok");
           alert(response.responseXML);

       },
        failure: function(response) {
          // KO
            alert("errpr");
            alert(response.resposeText);
       },
       xmlData: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld"><soap:Header/><soap:Body><HelloWorldResult>string</HelloWorldResult></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'
     });
```

This piece of code, is returning in responseText all the xml info I need, but is not showing up on responseXML. Furthermore I don't know how to look for the XML key and get the value.

The real problem comes across when I want to consume a bigger Service, in which I have to include some input parameters. The problem, it simply does not work. Perhaps jam doing it wrong. I'am just adding this to the other code before headers key.

```
params:{filter:'SomeName'}
```

I have been reading some sencha documentation, and I found out that there should be some way to create both model and sources to consume SOAP WebService, but I am not being able to do that. Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this somewhere. It's not mine:

In order for the browser to parse a returned XML document, the Content-Type header in the HTTP response must be set to "text/xml" or "application/xml". This is very important - the XmlReader will not work correctly otherwise.

Other than that you might want to go for JSON anyways.
Try this link:

```
http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json
```